# Symbolizing point feature with arrow to show azimuth in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am creating plot locations with a point feature class and I want to have an arrow coming off of the point to show direction from the plot. I have a field with azimuth values to use but I can't seem to find anything in the symbology properties that I could use to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to select Categories -> Unique values, and select any unique value to Add All your points.  Before clicking "Add All Values", go into the symbol properties for the  symbol to select an arrow:

[image]

Note the "Character Marker Symbol" from the drop-down Type, and the "ESRI North" from the font.  These arrows aren't in the default Symbol selections (shown on the left), so you'll have to go into the Edit Symbol... window.

After adding all symbol values, you can click the Advanced drop-down and click Rotation... from there you can select the field you want to use to rotate, or use an expression if you want or need to make updates to that field:

[image]